# django paginator, number of pages are not return

Tags: python, django, pagination

I want to use django.core.paginator, and I've problem with render_to_response function.
Variable named **pages** in views.py should return number of pages etc. but it isn't.
All stories i see but pagination not work. 
A **views.py** file look like:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
    from django.db.models import Q
    from cms.models import Story, Category
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

    def listing(request):
        story_list = Story.objects.all()
        p = Paginator(story_list, 2) # Show 2 contacts per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            pages = p.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
            pages = p.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
            pages = p.page(p.num_pages)
        return render_to_response('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/bin/project_003/cms/templates/cms/story_list.html', {"pages": pages})
```

And **story_list.html** like this:

```
    {% extends "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/bin/project_003/cms/templates/cms/base.html" %}
    {% block content %}
        {% if heading %}
            <h1>{{ heading }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
        <ul id="story-list">
            {% for story in story_list %}
                <li><a href="{{story.get_absolute_url}}">{{story.title}}</a></li><br>
        {{pages.p.num_pages}}
    {% endfor %}

    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if pages.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page={{ pages.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                Page {{ pages.number }} of {{ pages.paginator.num_pages }}.
            </span>

            {% if pages.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ pages.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
</ul>

    {% endblock %}
```

**Where I made mistake?**

Comment: That isn't your actual code, because you're not passing `story_list` to the template. The error though is that you are iterating over `story_list` rather than `pages`.

Comment: Also note that there is something *very* wrong with your TEMPLATE_DIRS setting if you are passing the full file path from the root as your template location in your view.

Comment: Also, you are returning `pages` as a `Page` object to the template. That means it's not a `Paginator` object from which you can get the number of pages.

Comment: you're right -- so how can I get the number of pages? iterating over `story in pages.object_list` not working also

Answer (score -1):

Straight from the docs, with changed variable names: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

**the view:**

```
def listing(request):
    story_list = Story.objects.all()
    p = Paginator(story_list, 2) # Show 2 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        stories = p.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        stories = p.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        stories = p.page(p.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/bin/project_003/cms/templates/cms/story_list.html', {"stories": stories})
```

**the template:**

```
<ul id="story-list">
    {% for story in stories %}
        <li><a href="{{story.get_absolute_url}}">{{story.title}}</a></li><br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if stories.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ stories.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ stories.number }} of {{ stories.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if stories.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ stories.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```